# Make columns standard width in html5 file

Tags: html, css

I would like to set the column length in the table to be the same length as the contents in the table.
Below is how I defined the column names:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Dataframe in Flask template</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <h2>Dashboard</h2>
    <table id="Mapped table" border="1">
       <tr>
        {% for col in column_names %}
        <th>{{col}}</th>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
      {% for row in rows %}
      <tr>
        {% for key, val in row.items() %}
          {% if key == link_column %}
          <td>
            <select class="dropbtn">
              {% for choice in choices %}
                <option value={{ choice[0] }}
                {% if choice[0] == val %} selected {% endif %}>
                  {{ choice[1] }}
                </option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
            {% elif key == link_column2 %}
          <td>
            <select class="dropbtn">
              {% for choice in choices2 %}
                <option value={{ choice[0] }}
                {% if choice[0] == val %} selected {% endif %}>
                  {{ choice[1] }}
                </option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
            {% elif key == link_column3 %}
              <td>
            <select class="dropbtn">
              {% for choice in choices3 %}
                <option value={{ choice[0] }}
                {% if choice[0] == val %} selected {% endif %}>
                  {{ choice[1] }}
                </option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
            {% elif key == link_column4 %}
          <td>
            <select class="dropbtn">
              {% for choice in choices4 %}
                <option value={{ choice[0] }}
                {% if choice[0] == val %} selected {% endif %}>
                  {{ choice[1] }}
                </option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
            {% elif key == link_column5 %}
          <td>
            <select class="dropbtn">
              {% for choice in choices5 %}
                <option value={{ choice[0] }}
                {% if choice[0] == val %} selected {% endif %}>
                  {{ choice[1] }}
                </option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
            {% elif key == link_column6 %}
          <td>
            <select class="dropbtn">
              {% for choice in choices6 %}
                <option value={{ choice[0] }}
                {% if choice[0] == val %} selected {% endif %}>
                  {{ choice[1] }}
                </option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
            {% elif key == link_column7 %}
          <td>
            <select class="dropbtn">
              {% for choice in choices7 %}
                <option value={{ choice[0] }}
                {% if choice[0] == val %} selected {% endif %}>
                  {{ choice[1] }}
                </option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
            {% elif key == link_column8 %}
          <td>
            <select class="dropbtn">
              {% for choice in choices8 %}
                <option value={{ choice[0] }}
                {% if choice[0] == val %} selected {% endif %}>
                  {{ choice[1] }}
                </option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
            {% elif key == link_column9 %}
          <td>
            <select class="dropbtn">
              {% for choice in choices9 %}
                <option value={{ choice[0] }}
                {% if choice[0] == val %} selected {% endif %}>
                  {{ choice[1] }}
                </option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
            {% elif key == link_column10 %}
          <td>
            <select class="dropbtn">
              {% for choice in choices10 %}
                <option value={{ choice[0] }}
                {% if choice[0] == val %} selected {% endif %}>
                  {{ choice[1] }}
                </option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
            {% elif key == link_column11 %}
          <td>
            <select class="dropbtn">
              {% for choice in choices11 %}
                <option value={{ choice[0] }}
                {% if choice[0] == val %} selected {% endif %}>
                  {{ choice[1] }}
                </option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
            {% elif key == link_column12 %}
          <td>
            <select class="dropbtn">
              {% for choice in choices12 %}
                <option value={{ choice[0] }}
                {% if choice[0] == val %} selected {% endif %}>
                  {{ choice[1] }}
                </option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
            {% elif key == link_column13 %}
          <td>
            <select class="dropbtn">
              {% for choice in choices13 %}
                <option value={{ choice[0] }}
                {% if choice[0] == val %} selected {% endif %}>
                  {{ choice[1] }}
                </option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
          </td>
          {% else %}
          <td>
            {{ val }}
          </td>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
  </div>
    <button class="button execute" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the table I obtain with my code. The columns with drop down option are using the content length.
I want the item description column to follow content width as well. Right now it is 'wrapped' I think?

[image]

Regards

Comment: Please give width to column and add *table-layout: fixed;* in your table

Comment: It would be good if you can provide us fully html code. :)

Comment: Hi Jaydeep, edited with full html code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table td:nth-child(4) {white-space: nowrap;}
```

try this css in your code

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Where do I add this bit of the code to? Sorry I'm a beginner to html codes.

Comment: <style>table td:nth-child(4) {white-space: nowrap;} </style> you can this into your head tag or in body tag of your html page